# What's the proper way of using property descriptors in Object.create?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I passed an object as the second parameter in the `Object.create` method, but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: 1

Here's the faulty code:

```
var test = Object.create(null, {
    ex1: 1,
    ex2: 2,
    meth: function () {
        return 10;
    },
    meth1: function () {
        return this.meth();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**`Object.create(proto, props)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) has two arguments:

> 1. `proto` — the object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object.
> 2. `props` (optional) — an object whose properties specify property descriptors to be added to the newly-created object, with the corresponding property names.

The format for the `props` object is defined [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

In short, the available options for each property descriptor are these:

```
{
    configurable: false, // or true
    enumerable: false, // or true
    value: undefined, // or any other value
    writable: false, // or true
    get: function () { /* return some value here */ },
    set: function (newValue) { /* set the new value of the property */ }
}
```

The problem with your code is that the property descriptors you've defined are not objects.

Here's an example of a proper usage of property descriptors:

```
var test = Object.create(null, {
    ex1: {
        value: 1,
        writable: true
    },
    ex2: {
        value: 2,
        writable: true
    },
    meth: {
        get: function () {
            return 'high';
        }
    },
    meth1: {
        get: function () {
            return this.meth;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: meth returns high - I cried. XD

Comment: Just wanted to add since ES2017 you can do var test = Object.create(null,  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors({...}) which returns a copy of the descriptor ( but definitively dood answer as it covers the mechanics behind object properties)

Answer (score -4):

Did you try this syntax :

```js
    var test = {
      ex1: 1,
      ex2: 2,
      meth: function() {
        return 10;
      },
      meth1: function() {
        return this.meth()
      }
    };

    console.log("test.ex1 :"+test.ex1);
    console.log("test.meth() :"+test.meth());
    console.log("test.meth1() :" + test.meth1() );
```